# Are all prime-order Fibonacci polynomials irreducible over $\Bbb{Z}$?

Tags: irreducible-polynomials, fibonacci-numbers

The Fibonacci polynomials are defined recursively as functions of one variable:
$$
F_0(z) = 0 \\
F_1(z) = 1 \\
\forall n > 1: F_n(z) = zF_{n-1}(z) + F_{n-2}(z)
$$
Thus for example $F_5(z) = 1+3z^2 + z^4$, and 
$$F_6(z) = 3z+4z^3+z^5 =z(1+z^2)(3+z^2) = F_2(z) F_3(z) (3+z^2) $$

It appears from several hundred examples that if a prime $p$ divides $n$ then $F_p(z)$ is a factor of $F_n(z)$.  If this conjecture is true, then   $F_n(z)$ is always reducible in $\Bbb{Z}(z)$ (that is,  $F_n(z)$ is factorable into more than one polynomial with degree at least one and integer coefficients) whenever $n$ is composite.  I suspect this is not too hard to prove.

It also appears, again from a large number of examples,  that for prime $p$,  $F_p(z)$ is always irreducible in 
$\Bbb{Z}(z)$.  But examples do not constitute a proof, and I don't see a good way of attacking the problem of proving irreducibility.

My question is, does anybody know of a proof that for prime $p$,  $F_p(z)$ is always irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}(z)$?

Comment: This might help: http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/12-2/hoggatt1.pdf